# Git 'Push to' Working but just 'Push' fails to push the code to remote in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am pretty sure I am missing some minor setting somewhere, but I have configured everything via the VSCode UI and not via any git commands.

I added the remote Via the UI that pops up

[image: add git remote]

I can see the remote when I use the push to screen.

[image: remote repo visible]

Now when I try to Push,

[image: Push]

I get this error

[image: git fatal vscode push]

And the log

[image: git vscode log]

This is what it looks like from a terminal outside of VSCode.

[image: terminal output]

*Disclaimer, I know how I to fix this via general git commands, but I want to link the remote to push to the repo when I just click on `Push` and I shouldn't have to do `Push to`. Is there a branch setting I am forgetting?*

In the end, my Question is,

**How do I make it the "default" repo VSCode pushes to without using any sort of git commands, and just from VSCode UI alone.**

Comment: Typically the default remote is named `origin`.

Comment: Yes, but how Do i do set it through VSCode UI?

Comment: You need to set the remote for this branch.

Comment: @matt the remote is already added, check 2nd pic, `push to` pushes fine, just `push` fails

Comment: I didn't say the remote. I said the remote _for this branch_. The equivalent of `git branch -u origin mybranch`.

Comment: @matt I can do that yes, but I want to do it via the VSCode UI and not git commands as I said. bear with me now :D because how come when I do a `Push to` and select the remote it works without me setting any branch for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it finally!

You have to click on the little `Synchronize Changes` icon in the status bar which will sync the remote's commits etc and then you can you use `Push`

[image: synchronize]

[image: sync question]

After Syncing, the branches are linked in VSCode. No need of any Git Commands! :D

You should be seeing both the local and remote branches.

[image: local and remote branches]